# htmlagilitypack website datatable extract data

Tags: c#, html, datatable, html-agility-pack

Yes, I have searched the web and stackoverflow. I am having trouble extracting data from a table from a website. I can retrieve the full table with code below, but need to extract select data:

```
Url = "https://www.multpl.com/shiller-pe/table/by-month";
web = new HtmlWeb();
doc = web.Load(Url);
pe = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='datatable']").InnerText.ToString();
Console.Write(pe);
```

Xpath //*[@id='datatable']/tbody/tr[3]/td[2] for a data point does not work and throws error.
This also does not work:

```
Url = "https://www.multpl.com/shiller-pe/table/by-month";
web = new HtmlWeb();
doc = web.Load(Url);
var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='datatable']");
var tableRows = table.SelectNodes("tr");
var columns = tableRows[0].SelectNodes("th/text()");
for (int i = 1; i < tableRows.Count; i++)
{ 
for (int e = 0; e < columns.Count; e++)
    {
    var value = tableRows[i].SelectSingleNode("td[e + 1]");
    Console.Write(columns[e].InnerText + ":" + value.InnerText);
    }
}
```

Any direction will help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution finally.

```
            Url = "https://www.multpl.com/shiller-pe/table/by-month";
            web = new HtmlWeb();
            doc = web.Load(Url);
            foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='right']"))
            {
              numberList.Add(Convert.ToDouble(node.InnerText));
              //Print(node.InnerText.ToString());

            }
            Print(numberList[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found 2 problems.

1. The main problem is in your xpath `td[e + 1]`. You try to use `e` variable but not using [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated). Change your code to next one:

```
var value = tableRows[i].SelectSingleNode($"td[{e + 1}]");
```

2. Second one is about `th/text()` selector. You want to count columns so change it to `th`. Html code in [`https://www.multpl.com/shiller-pe/table/by-month`](https://www.multpl.com/shiller-pe/table/by-month) has a few elements for second column in header but single element in the table so it'll be right sing to use `th` selector.

The second column's header is still specific so you will still have issues with `columns[e].InnerText`. May be it's better to handle it manually. Column values can be trimmed too because there is line separators in second column. Here is my final code:

```
public void ParseTable()
{
    string Url = "https://www.multpl.com/shiller-pe/table/by-month";
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
    var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='datatable']");
    var tableRows = table.SelectNodes("//tr");

    var columns = tableRows[0].SelectNodes("th"); // fixed

    for (int i = 1; i < tableRows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int e = 0; e < columns.Count; e++)
        {
            var value = tableRows[i].SelectSingleNode($"td[{e + 1}]"); // fixed
            Console.Write(GetColumnName(columns[e]) + ": " + value.InnerText.Trim()); // fixed
            if (e < columns.Count - 1)
            {
                Console.Write(" | ");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

private static string GetColumnName(HtmlNode thNode)
{
    var spanValue = thNode.SelectSingleNode("span[@class='value']");
    if (spanValue != null)
        return spanValue.InnerText.Trim();
    
    var spanTitle = thNode.SelectSingleNode("span[@class='title']");
    return spanTitle != null 
        ? spanTitle.InnerText.Trim() 
        : thNode.InnerText.Trim();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I found a simple solution that works for me.